# Alamofire's Session timeOutInterval and cachePolicy setting is not reflected on URLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Struggling to understand how Alamofire's (5.2.2) sets the timeOutInterval and cachePolicy for requests.

I have the following setup:

```
// Create Alamofire Session with custom cache and timeout interval settings
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
let session = Session(configuration: configuration)

// Create request and leaving request's timeout interval (60) and cache policy (rawValue - 0) on default.
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://github.com")!)

// Fire request
session.request(request).response { response in
    print("### cachePolicy: \(response.request?.cachePolicy.rawValue)") // 0
    print("### timeoutInterval: \(response.request?.timeoutInterval)") // 60
    print("### session config: \(session.sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest)") // 30
    print("### session cachePolicy: \(session.sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy.rawValue)") // 1
}
```

What is the source of through for these configuration options? The configuration or the request?
Will be whatever is defined in `URLSessionConfiguration` actually used?
If yes, should that not overwrite the common properties in `URLRequest` as well?
Is it not overwritten because the `URLRequest` instance is copied before the session configuration settings would be applied to the request?

Answer (score 0):

The `request` captured by Alamofire's various `*Response` types is the last `URLRequest` *Alamofire* saw before handing it off to the underlying `URLSession` to actually perform, so it will not reflect the `URLRequest` actually performed by any of the tasks. If you need that information, you can capture Alamofire's `DataRequest` and query the `task?.currentRequest`.

```
let request = session.request(request)
response.response { response in 
    // Access request.task?.currentRequest
}
```